# AppendChild element in div on nth position

Tags: jquery

Basically I have three `div` element, And I want to append child element `<P>` after `<div class="div1"></div>`.

my code is:

```
<div class="div1">
            <p></p>
            <section class="section"></section>
 </div>
<div  class="div2"></div>
```

i have try this one

```
$('.div1').appendChild('<p>hello world!!</p>');
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `.after()`:

```
$('.div1').after('<p>hello world!!</p>');
```

```js
$('.div1').after('<p>new p</p>');
```

```css
div{border:red solid 1px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <p>inner p in div1 </p>
  <section class="section">inner section in div 1</section>
</div>
<div class="div2">div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.div1+.div2').before('<p>hello world!!</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
            <p>test1</p>
            <section class="section"></section>
 </div>
<div  class="div2">
     <p>test2</p>
    
</div>
```

Comment: _I want to append child element <P> after <div class="div1"></div>?_ this is the question.

Comment: i think you want insert p tag on div1 between div2? is it correct?

Comment: $('.div1').insertAfter('<p>hello world!!</p>');

Comment: yes thats true i want add p tag between div1 and div2.

Comment: @Jignesh_creolesstudios so isn't my answer does that thing? you can see above.

Comment: $('.div1+.div2').before('<p>hello world!!</p>');